# UX article/study on CLS (cumulative layout shift)

Tags: layout

I’m struggling to find any article/study on CLS from UX perspective, almost all resources I found are written from SEO standpoint. Please could anyone point to any article/study? Many thanks

Comment: What exactly  do you want to know about it? Seems hard to find any articles as the measure was only introduced by Google around 2020 (That's the earliest mention I could find)

Comment: In simpler words, I'm searching for a UX article/study on the impact of interface layout shifts (while loading or any other scenario) to the user. I mentioned CLS metric for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some of the articles written about the impact of [CLS](https://web.dev/articles/cls) on user experience, it seems like these are the main takeaways:

**Credibility**: If a website's layout shifts unpredictably, it gives the user an impression that it is not as professional or trustworthy to users. This is important for conversion rates if you intend to nudge the users to a particular action.

**Mistakes**: A high CLS can lead to a frustrating user experience caused by elements on a page suddenly move or shift while a user is interacting with them, which then can result in unintended clicks.

**Performance**: A high degree of CLS is also associated with delays because of the time taken to readjust the layout from working out the changes required, and leads to more wait time for the users before they can interact with the interface.